# Hide gameobjects dynamically in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I hide objects behind other objects in unity 2D dynamically?

Example: I have a cactus asset in my scene and want to be able to place a random number of collectibles behind the cactus, so that the collectibles are visible to the player. If possible, I also want to be able to determine the degree of visibility.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBuBM.jpg

Comment: You can change the depth value for the cactus and the collectibles. Or you could just update the Z value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the orthographic camera, then the z axis value will not make a difference. The orthographic camera does not have any sense of depth. What you want to manipulate is the sorting layer property on the sprite renderer component.

Answer (score 0):

Make all the the objects you wanna hide children of the cactus.
I assume each child has a sprite renderer component, as you are using visible 2d objects.

the order of sprites is determined with "sorting order" attribute. so here is a piece of code that gives all the other objects a lower order so they go behind the cactus.

```
SpriteRenderer[] renderers = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer> ();

for(int i =0 ; i< renderers.Length; i++){
    renderers [i].sortingOrder = -1 * i;
}
```

this code changes the order of children, but if you want to make them invisible, use transform.enabled=false for each child